# Using JavaScript unable to work out how to log into organizational ArcGIS Enterprise Portal

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have written an ArcGIS app using JavaScript API 4.23 accessing ArcGIS online (personal account). The code is stored in an .html file I have saved on my hard drive. I now want to point the app at my companies enterprise portal, but searching I cannot find a way to access the portal using JavaScript. Currently I login into my company portal UI pressing the blue button below (I do not need to enter any credentials).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must register an "App" item in the Portal, which will give you an "appId", and then use `esri/portal/Portal` and `esri/identity/OAuthInfo`. Here is a tutorial that steps you through the steps: [Access ArcGIS Online items using OAuth 2.0](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/identity-oauth-basic/)

Comment: Thank you that doesn't work. I have tried that.